# Style tags into index.html file

Tags: angular-dart

The build generate `<style>` tags into `index.html` file. Is there any way to change that? Generate all css in a separate file for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's how Angular works. The styles are updated at runtime for style encapsulation purposes and are generated by code. Having them in a CSS file wouldn't work.

If you don't use component styles but a reference to a CSS file in `index.html` then this will taken as is for the generated app.

Comment: Ok, I got it. My goal with the question was to figure out a way to implement themes that changes at runtime. Could you advice some pattern to implement themes in an angular dart app?

Comment: I donßt think there is an easy way. You can check the angular_components repository, I think they started basic theme support.The easiest is probably to use sass and build a versions of the app for each theme.